# jQuery: Hover-Over Slide Panel

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way to do a slide out panel when you hover over specific images on my website similar to what Google Search does.

I'd also need this panel to display another website page. Which I am sure can be done using `iframe` or PHP's cURL.

Here is an example similar to what I am looking for:
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, I am not very good with jQuery, but mostly because I haven't found the plugin I need.

Comment: lol yes, I found one! But it's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy, you don't need a plugin:

HTML

```
<img id="imgHover" src="img/photo.png"/>
<div id="panel">
    <iframe src="http://www.website.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#panel").hide();
$("#imgHover").hover(
    function(){
        $("#panel").slideDown();
    },
    function(){
        $("div").slideUp();
    }   
)
```

Working exemple:

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkas/SULhT/

Update

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkas/aFXNC/

Comment: Doesn't work and I'd need it to slide to the right, not down. Thank you though. http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/D6Xsh/3/

Comment: it does work, wait for the site to fully load. and for slide on the right, you better take a look to the animate function (http://api.jquery.com/animate/). play with the width option.

Comment: Damn, I like that last example a lot except it will end up covering one of the images they are hovering over. I ended up just using the plugin in my OP. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty similar to the one you mentioned but have you looked Mosaic?

http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/1.0/